# Compiling Reason source files to the same directory as the source files

Tags: reason, bucklescript, bsconfig

I'm writing a node application, where I would like to mix Reason and raw JavaScript.

[This section](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/Manual.html#_in_source_build_support_since_1_9_0) in the bucklescript documentation describes it

> When user has an existing JS project, it makes sense to output the JS
>   file in the same directory as vanilla JS, the schema added a key
>   called `in-source` so that generate JS file next to ML file.

I assume that this is in the `bsconfig.json` file? But what value should the key have? [The schema documentation](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/docson/#build-schema.json) does not mention this option.

I'm running Bucklescript version 1.9.1 - so the functionality should be available (available since 1.9.0).

How do I use the `in-source` option?

My `bsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "re-server",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bsc-flags": ["-bs-super-errors"],
  "in-source": true,  // I tried adding the key here
  "sources": [{
    "dir": "src",
    "in-source": true  // I tried adding the key here
  }
  ],
  "bs-dependencies" : [
    "bs-express"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be in the "package-specs" section:

```
{
  ...
  "package-specs" : [{
    "module": ...,
    "in-source": true
  }]
}
```

So your `bsconfig.json` should look like:

```
{
  "name": "re-server",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bsc-flags": ["-bs-super-errors"],
  "package-specs" : [{
    "module": "commonjs",
    "in-source": true
  }],
  "sources": [{
    "dir": "src"
  }
  ],
  "bs-dependencies" : [
    "bs-express"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'll make sure to submit a documentation fix for this, too.

Comment: Great, I had to add a `"module": "commonjs"` too inside the package spec object for it to compile, but now it's fine. Did you update the schema-doc already? Because now I can find it - but you have to click to drill down to the option to see it.

Comment: It's always been there, just hiding very well ;) I haven't updated the schema, just the manual. I'll add "module" too. Thought it was optional, but apparently not.